# sqlcmd to insert from csv into sql table

Tags: sql, csv, import, sqlcmd

How can I use sqlcmd to insert data from a csv file into an existing SQL table? The below command is not working.

```
sqlcmd -S <servername> -U <username> -P <password> -d <dbname> -i c:\test.csv -s "|" -o "dbo.sqltable"
```

I cannot use Bulk import or the Import wizard on SSMS.

Comment: *is not working* - how? Do you get an error - if so: ***what*** error? Does it just not import any data? Does it import the data but wrongly? Please clarify

Comment: This isn't sqlcmd, but a quick and dirty solution to this can be to open the csv in excel, then add a computed column that includes your sql statement along with variables for the cells in the imported csv columns, so that the output becomes a proper sql command.  Then you can just copy/paste that into SSMS or however you prefer to execute .sql files.